# How do I keep data persistent while the App is running?

Tags: swiftui, combine

**Scenario:**  I retrieve data from a server via **@ObservableObject**/**@Publish**; within a **tabview()**.

Data is displayed as expected.  
However when I return to the tabView from another tab, I data is gone, requiring me to do another fetch which isn't needed.

Here's the subscriber:

```
struct NYTStatesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataSource = NYTStatesModel()
    ...
}
```

Here's the publisher:

```
final class NYTStatesModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var revisedNYTStates: RevisedNYTStates!
    // ...
}
```

**dataSource.revisedNYTStates** *is empty* upon return to the View.

**Question:**  *How do I RETAIN the data* so I don't have to ***always*** access the server per View display?

Answer (score 2):

When you're switching tabs, `dataSource` is recreated:

```
struct NYTStatesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataSource = NYTStatesModel()
    ...
}
```

A solution may be to create `dataSource` *outside* the TabView.

For example on the app level:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject private var dataSource = NYTStatesModel()

    ...
}
```

(or in the `SceneDelegate` for SwiftUI 1.0)

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I struggled with for a while too. There are a couple of different ways to do what you want.

The first is creating a loader class from somewhere higher up in the view hierarchy and passing it down to where it is needed. For example, you might create the loader in the the app main struct and passing it in as an environment object. IMO, this method is the least scalable and the messiest.

The second option is to either use a singleton or a static property to persist your data. For example you could make your NYTStatesModel a singleton. (I don't condone this type of behavior)

The third (and best IMO) is creating a class that is responsible for caching your results and passing that into the view model from the environment. NSCache will actually dump results when your phone is running low on memory. Here's two articles that will help. The first is how to create a cache and the second is how to create an environment key.

https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/caching-in-swift/

https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/08/21/the-power-of-environment-in-swiftui/

Just use dependency injection to check the cache before the network call. The cache is persisted in the environment.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.   The Singleton approach was very simple; but got to be congested with all the data gathered.  The beauty with a Singleton is... you can access all the data ahead of time, prior to showing the View to avoid the delay when initially displaying the View.  The data is right there ahead of time.

Comment: Right, you could load your data at any point in the application. Another cool thing about static properties is that they are initialized lazily so if the first time you use it could be when that view is shown